# Create a function that computes how many proper fractions you can build with a given denominator using Python

Tags: python

Objective: Build a function that computes how many proper fractions you can build with a given denominator

Problem: Codewars is a platform used for the code submission. Upon submission it will not accept my code because it is not efficient even though I passed all test cases. Can someone please suggest me how could I optimize my code even more

Code:

```
from fractions import Fraction 

def proper_fractions(n):
    
    count = 0
    
    for i in range(1,n):
        fractionA = Fraction(i, n) 
        if fractionA.denominator == n:
            count+=1
    
    return count
```

Sample Tests:

```
Test.assert_equals(proper_fractions(1),0)
Test.assert_equals(proper_fractions(2),1)
Test.assert_equals(proper_fractions(5),4)
Test.assert_equals(proper_fractions(15),8)
Test.assert_equals(proper_fractions(25),20)
```

Comment: By not efficient, do you mean that you are you getting time limit exceeded? Maybe provide a link to the problem?

Comment: I think Euler's totient function is relevant here, will count # of  numbers up to N that are coprime with N.

Comment: @idontknow Codewars will execute your code within a certain time limit i guess and myne is taking long time for their server to process which means the code needs to be optimized

Comment: @ApplicationTeam optimization as in algorithm-wise. This is pure brute-foce, and will get TLE on larger test cases for sure.

Comment: @idontknow what do you mean by TLE?

Comment: TLE = Time Limit Exceeded
ME = Memory Exceeded
WA = Wrong Answer
AC = Accepted

Comment: @MarkDickinson yes

Answer (score 0):

This should be 7 to 8 times faster:

```
from math import gcd

def fracCount(N): return sum(gcd(d,N)==1 for d in range(1,N))
```

For a given N, there will be a maximum of N-1 fractions : 1/N, 2/N, 3/N ... (N-1)/N.  The ones that are not proper fractions are when the numerator and denominator can be divided by a common divider (which we can detect with gcd).

output:

```
print(fracCount(1))  # 0
print(fracCount(2))  # 1
print(fracCount(5))  # 4
print(fracCount(15)) # 8
print(fracCount(25)) # 20
```

**[EDIT]**

For an even faster solution, you can obtain the "improper" numerators by finding all multiples of the prime factors of N.  You need a function that returns prime factors such as the one below.  Subtract the number of these improper numerators from N-1 to get the count of proper fraction

```
def primeDivs(N):
    p = 2
    while N>=p*p:
        if N%p == 0:   yield p
        while N%p==0:  N //= p
        p += 1 + (p&1)
    if N>1 : yield N

def fracCount(N):
    return N-1-len({f for p in primeDivs(N) for f in range(p,N,p)})
```

This one is roughly 100 times faster than proper_fractions()

**[EDIT2]** Using Euler's totient function is even faster (on large values of N):

```
def totient(N):
    tot  = N
    for p in primeDivs(N):
        tot -= tot//p
    return tot

def properFractions(N): return 0 if N<2 else totient(N)
```

It's more than 3000 times faster than proper_fractions for N = 10000.

Comment: We have the same issue where it timed out on execution. I may have to try Euler's function